# Firebase console does not display data

Tags: firebase, console, firebase-realtime-database

I received this error in my browser console:

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://s-usc1c-nss-109.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5&ns=dashroad-fleet-management' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

If I navigate to other projects in Firebase, their data load and display just fine.

Edit 1: New error in browser console upon page reload:

> WebSocket connection to
>   'wss://s-usc1c-nss-109.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5&ns=dashroad-fleet-management'
>   failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
>
> qh.open @
>   third_party/javascript/firebase/firebase_js_minified.jslib:176

Edit 2: If I let the browser tab be, eventually the data is loaded once the WebSocket connection is established (the WebSocket Connection error stops appearing)

Answer (score 1):

If this error occurs in chrome, just ignore it. There was a problem with webkit \ chrome, some websocket related issues.
This error can also occur due to malformed URL.

**What does Err_name_not_resolved mean?**

DNS is the network service that translates a website's name to its Internet address. This error is most often caused by having no connection to the Internet or a misconfigured network. It can also be caused by an unresponsive DNS server or a firewall preventing Google Chrome from accessing the network.

*Source google*

**net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED**

This seems to DNS resolution problem. Enter DNS servers addresses manually in the Internet Protocol (IP) v4 settings in your computer network settings. Use public DNS addresses such as 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4, 4.2.2.2 etc.

Comment: For the other projects that display data just fine, this error does not appear in the browser console (I am using Chrome). This error also comes with a counter that increases gradually, which suggest the browser keeps trying to establish the WebSocket connection but failed.

Comment: try other browser.
Which version of chrome you are using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit). Data doesn't load in Firefox or Safari too.

Comment: Please see the Updated answer